# convert directed graph to Json file python

Tags: python, json, directed-graph

I'm Converting dictionary to a directed graph then I'm trying saving that graph as a JSON file in this code:

```
def main():
    g = {"a": ["d"],
         "b": ["c"],
         "c": ["b", "c", "d", "e"],
         "d": ["a", "c"],
         "e": ["c"],
         "f": []
         }

    graph = DirectedGraph()
    for key in g.keys():
        graph.add(key)
        elements = g[key]
        for child in elements:
            graph.add_edge(key, child)

    with open('JJ.json', 'w') as output_file:
        json.dump(graph, output_file)


main()
```

Its giving me an error at json.dump as

> Object of type 'DirectedGraph' is not JSON serializable

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you post the code for DirectedGraph ? Is this a custom class you created ? What JSON format are you expecting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON module only knows how to serialize basic python types. while using dump to add Object in this case (graph), [Serialize arbitrary Python objects to JSON using **dict**](http://www.marcstober.com/blog/2007/07/07/serializing-arbitrary-python-objects-to-json-using-__dict__/)

I've just edited my code to:

```
with open(f'{string_input}.json', 'w') as output_file:
    json.dump(graph.__dict__, output_file)
```

and it worked perfictly.